# Clear/Remove multiple ViewController in NavigationController

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

I hope you can help me with this issue.

I am developing this iOS application with multiple ViewControllers, as shown in the following image.
[image]

I navigate from VC1 to VC2, VC2 to VC3 until I reach VCn. When I arrive at this ViewController, I need to go to VC4. I know I could go with a segue to VC4, but the problem is that it would be stored in the navigation stack, which I want to avoid.

How can I navigate to VC4 from VCn while also clearing the navigation stack (VC2, VC3... VCn), and then return to VC1 from VC4?

I hope you can help me!

Comment: Do you want to go to a *new* VC4, or do you want to go back to the existing VC4?

Comment: @Sweeper I want to go to VC4 that has not yet been made visible in the navigation, it is not in the navigation stack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is to set the navigation controller's `viewControllers` property to an array of two elements - the root view controller (VC1), and the new VC4.

```
if let navigationController {
    let vc4 = ... // initialise VC4 appropriately
    // make the array
    let newStack = [navigationController.viewControllers[0], vc4]
    // this sets viewControllers, with a "push" transition
    navigationController.setViewControllers(newStack, animated: true)
}
```

If you want a "pop" transition instead, first remove all the elements in `viewControllers` except the first and the last, then insert VC4 in between the remaining 2 VCs. Then you can `popViewController(animated: true)` to go to VC4.

```
if let navigationController {
    let vc4 = ... 
    navigationController.viewControllers.removeSubrange(1..<navigationController.viewControllers.count - 1)
    navigationController.viewControllers.insert(vc4, at: 1)
    navigationController.popViewController(animated: true)
}
```